# Android: Clear Activity Stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I'm having several activities in my application. and flow is very complicated. When I click the Logout application navigates to login Screen and from there user can exit by cancel button (calling `system.exit(0)` )

when I exit or back button, the system invokes an activity from stack :( how can I clear all the activities in the stack when I reach Login screen? calling `finish()` is not practical as there are so many activities and some activities should no be closed when they are active such as native camera invoking activity.

```
validateuser logoutuser = new validateuser();
logoutuser.logOut();
Intent loginscreen = new Intent(homepage.this, Login2.class);
(homepage.this).finish();
loginscreen.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(loginscreen);
```

Comment: check this link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139686/exit-an-android-app/5140545#5140545

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Clear the back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack)

Answer (score 369, accepted):

Most of you are wrong. If you want to close existing activity stack regardless of what's in there and create new root, correct set of flags is the following:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

[From the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK):

> `public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`
>   Added in API level 11
>
> If set in an Intent passed to
>   `Context.startActivity()`, this flag will cause any existing task that
>   would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the
>   activity is started. That is, the activity becomes the new root of an
>   otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished. This can
>   only be used in conjunction with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. Strangely didn't give error with minSDK=9.

Comment: Frankly I never used this functionality, resurrect after crash, etc., and rather focused on fixing the issues that caused crash )

Comment: Same functionality also provides `IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask` from support library.

Comment: Adding only those two flags leaves activity stack track behind (starts on top of the previous one), then added  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP which simply restarts the application and then exits totally. I haven't added any flag to activities explicitly tho. What could be the problem?

Comment: Doesn't send to work with singleInstance launchMode activities

Comment: One of the best beginnings: "Most of you are wrong."

Answer (score 30):

When you call `startActivity` on the last activity you could always use

> `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

as a flag on that intent.

Read more about the flag [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Comment: that also doesn't help. I just brings up an activity dat doesn't ended with finish(); :(

Comment: I guess FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP clears the activities on the top. My problem is activities on the bottom :(

Comment: I guess it depends on how the flow actually is. You should read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Could be, try to use the flag more or maybe try to improve your flow. Perhaps as singleTask or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for showing correct resources. the mistake i did was closing the Login activity. I should not close it. When the activity loaded first. so when I call it back using Clear_top flag, login activity clears all the activities on the top. since login is the first entrace activity, it clears all the activities started after. so bingo it worked :)

Comment: From the documentation, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP clears the stack **only if** the specific activity "already running in the current task"

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka good notice. Whats the solution if activity is not *already* running!

Comment: @Umka you should link in that case. "below" is just now, answers my shift in their ordering.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple helper method for starting a new activity as the new top activity which works from API level 4 up until the current version 17:

```
static void startNewMainActivity(Activity currentActivity, Class<? extends Activity> newTopActivityClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, newTopActivityClass);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        intent.addFlags(0x8000); // equal to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK which is only available from API level 11
    currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

call it like this from your current activity:

```
startNewMainActivity(this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: Couldn't you than always just use intent.addFlags(0x8000); and simplify that?

Comment: As this flag was first introduced in Honeycomb I have no idea what implication it might have on earlier versions. So, this was me being precaucios. But I guess removal of the conditial shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: you want to add that flag when API level is < 11 then you need to do `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` else `intent.addFlags(0x8000);` will never added

Comment: I am having the user go by many activities one after the other through intents. Do I need to do anything in order to make sure the app doesn't crash with too many activities on the stack? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

**Clear Activity Backstate** by below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Your_Current_Activity.this, Your_Destination_Activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Done**

Comment: I am having the user go by many activities one after the other through intents. Do I need to do anything in order to make sure the app doesn't crash with too many activities on the stack? Thanks!

Comment: @RuchirBaronia, If you go A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G -> H, now H -> I you write my code than I will be Last Activity after then you press Back button app will close because app has no backstate activity, hope this will help you.

Comment: Do I need to do that though? What will happen if I never clean activity stack?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia, Backpress: H -> G -> F -> E -> D -> C -> B -> A

Comment: But some time it shows white screen while calling new activity. Ho to solve this?

Comment: Adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP restarts the application and then exits totally. I haven't added any flag to activities explicitly tho. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  //It is use to finish current activity
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

Comment: why you are using both  `this.finish()` and `setFlags()` also to clear current activity  ?

Answer (score 4):

This decision works fine:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

But new activity launch long and you see white screen some time. If this is critical then use this workaround:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String ACTION_FINISH = "action_finish";

    private BroadcastReceiver finisBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        registerReceiver(finisBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                finish();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(ACTION_FINISH));
    }

    public void clearBackStack() {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(finisBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

How use it:

```
public class ActivityA extends BaseActivity {

    // Click any button
    public void startActivityB() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
        clearBackStack();
    }
}
```

Disadvantage: all activities that must be closed on the stack must extends BaseActivity

Answer (score 4):

### Using Kotlin:

You can set the flag directly using setter method. In Kotlin `or` is the [replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45996002/974045) for the Java bitwise or `|`.

```
intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

If you plan to use this regularly, create an Intent extension function

```
fun Intent.clearStack() {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
```

You can then directly call this function before starting the intent

```
intent.clearStack()
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, LoginActivity was closed as well. As a result,

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

did not help.

However, setting

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

helped me.

Comment: I am having the user go by many activities one after the other through intents. Do I need to do anything in order to make sure the app doesn't crash with too many activities on the stack? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I noted that you asked for a solution that does not rely on `finish()`, but I wonder if this may help nonetheless.

I tracked whether an exit flag is raised with a static class variable, which survives the entire app lifespan. In each *relevant* activity's `onResume()`, use

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ExitHelper.isExitFlagRaised) {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

The ExitHelper class

```
public class ExitHelper {
    public static boolean isExitFlagRaised = false;
}
```

Let's say in mainActivity, a user presses a button to exit - you can set `ExitHelper.isExitFlagRaised = true;` and then `finish()`. Thereafter, other relevant activities that are resumed automatically will be finished as well.

Comment: what will happen if I use the code in MainActivity onresume() then come back to mainactivity from 2nd activity onbackpress

Answer (score 3):

For Xamarin Developers, you can use:

```
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();