# How to remove an activity from a the stack

Tags: android

I am making an application in which i want to make sure that only one instance of a single activity should remain in the stack.Please tell me how to achieve that.This is the coding which i was trying but have not got the intended result.

```
ArrayList<String> runningactivities = new ArrayList<String>();

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 

    List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE); 

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < services.size(); i1++) { 
            runningactivities.add(0,services.get(i1).topActivity.toString());  
        } 

        if(runningactivities.contains("ComponentInfo{com.velosys.interview_preparation/com.velosys.interview_preparation.activities.MCQ}")==true){
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Activity is in foreground, active",1000).show(); 
            //MCQ.
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked out a similar question like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075349/android-clear-activity-stack

Comment: Also, doesn't `finish()` clear the activity from the stack?

Comment: Sir actually i want to do like this.      Activity A-> B ->C->A->B  Only the latest instance of A should remain there and the previous instances should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a typical case for an **Activity Launch Mode**.

The official Android documentation is pretty precise and coherent imho.

Check out the paragraph [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). The *singleTask* mode might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

put inside the onStop() or the onPause() methods of the activity the "finish()" command. So every time you exit this activity it will be removed from the activity stack , so there will be no duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

you can set intent flags while launching your activities. In your case `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Comment: Sir actually i want to do like this. Activity A-> B ->C->A->B Only the latest instance of A should remain there and the previous instances should be removed.

Comment: In this case while launch B you should call `finish()` for Activity A just after your startActivity() call for B, and so on