# Managing Activities - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have a problem with maintaining the activities.

I have activity A, and when starting Activity B from Notification, I should end Activity A, and start Activity B.

In other words, At a same time, in stack, Only Activity A or Activity B should be present. Its' very easy achieve when am starting Activity B from Activity A, by calling `finish()` in Activity A. But cannot achieve the same when starting activity from notification.

Stack should be like this,

- MainActivity -- Activity A
- MainActivity -- Activity B (When starting activity B from notification)

But My Stack looks like,

- MainActivity -- Activity A -- Activity B

What Intent flags or launch mode should be used for this.

Comment: Have you tried the accepted answer from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403364/clear-activity-stack-and-start-new-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your notification to send a `PendingIntent` to Activity A, process it in `onNewIntent()` and have it start Activity B, finishing Activity A as you described.

Comment: Ya this sounds good.. But in my case, there are about 4 activities.. out of which only one should opened at a time.. Should I put all those 4 activities in a single task and clear the task each time I initiate another activity?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into using Fragments.  You can use a single activity and just present the appropriate Fragment based upon the incoming `Intent`.

Answer (score 1):

[ClearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Clearing)

> If this attribute is set to "true" in the root activity of a task, the stack is cleared down to the root activity whenever the user leaves the task and returns to it.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you call `finish()` in **`onStop()`** of both activities,

in this manner you will always have one activity On, down side of it as soon as you go somewhere apart from these activity they will be closed and you will loss that data,

looking as your current requirement I think only one `Activity` should live so this might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

in your manifest where you declare your activites.

See [documentation of launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).