# How to combine Intent flags in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin, bitwise-operators

I want to combine two intent flags as we do below in Android:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I tried doing something like this but it didn't work for me:

```
val intent = Intent(context, MapActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

**Explanation:**

The operation that is applied to the flags is a bitwise or. In Java you have the `|` operator for that.

> As of bitwise operations [in Kotlin], there're no special characters
>   for them, but just named functions that can be called in infix form.

[Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#operations)

Here a list of all bitwise operations for `Int` and `Long`

- `shl(bits)` – signed shift left (Java's `<<`)
- `shr(bits)` – signed shift right (Java's `>>`)
- `ushr(bits)` – unsigned shift right (Java's `>>>`)
- `and(bits)` – bitwise and (Java's `&`)
- `or(bits)` – bitwise or (Java's `|`)
- `xor(bits)` – bitwise xor (Java's `^`)
- `inv()` – bitwise inversion (Java's `~`)

**Solution:**

So, in your case you only need to call `or` in between your arguments like so.

```
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Comment: Does or execute only one of them? Can I use and?

Comment: I know how bitwise or works but with the naming of the bitwise or operator as 'or', at first glance 'FlagA or FlagB' does not convey that in fact this is a combination of FlagA and FlagB.

Answer (score 17):

Try something like following:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MapsActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Answer (score 5):

### Advanced, Reuseable Kotlin:

In Kotlin `or` is the replacement for the Java bitwise or `|`.

```
intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

If you plan to use your combination regularly, create an Intent extension function

```
fun Intent.clearStack() {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
```

You can then directly call this function before starting the intent

```
intent.clearStack()
```

If you need the option to add additional flags in other situations, add an optional param to the extension function.

```
fun Intent.clearStack(additionalFlags: Int = 0) {
    flags = additionalFlags or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
```