# I can not finish the Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

My problem is this ... I have 3 Activities:

(ActivityA), (ActivityB) and (ActivityC)

From ActivityA to ActivityB I use the following code:

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

From ActivityB to ActivityC I also use this code:

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityC::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

But if I give onBackPressed or go to any other App and return to my App, instead of returning to ActivityC, it goes to ActivityA.

Comment: Btw, you can combine multiple flags together with the `or` bitwise operator (aka `intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or /* … */` instead of calling `intent.addFlags` multiple times). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995425/how-to-combine-intent-flags-in-kotlin for more info.

Comment: chech this library. Annotation based: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` from the `Intent` for starting `Activity C`, as the flag prevents the new activity from being added to the back stack and finishes the activity when it is navigated away from. This means your app will start  with it's launcher activity, which I assume is `Activity A`. You can read more about this [flag here in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY).

Answer (score 0):

From Activity A to Activity B do like this -

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

And from Activity B to Activity C do like this -

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityC::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY).**

It does clear the history of current activity.