# How to destroy an android activity after when I sending a post with a web service?

Tags: android, postgresql, android-studio, android-asynctask, glassfish

I'm trying to submit a form using a web service done with [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/) in Java and save the data in a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database. I am using AsyncTask to send data. The problem I have is that when I've finish sending the data I want to destroy the activity and return to the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are in a sub-method, listeners, etc.:

```
youractivityclass.this.finish();
```

if you are directly on your activity class just call

```
finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

just call `finish();` in order to destroy your `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish();` when you want to kill the Activity.

See link for further research: [How to kill an Android activity when leaving it so that it cannot be accessed from the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550099/how-to-kill-an-android-activity-when-leaving-it-so-that-it-cannot-be-accessed-fr)