# Trying to kill my app

Tags: android, kill

I'm trying to force close my app in order to hide what user did. I'm using the next code (that is half-working). It disappears from the screen but in when I press the button of the open apps (the button on the bottom, next to home and back buttons) I still can see it.
Do you guys know what is the best way to kill the app completely?

```
 finish();
 moveTaskToBack(true);
 System.exit(0);
```

I'm gonna try to explain it better:
The thing is i have an activity, when i press the specified Button it opens another one that has a timer. if the user doesn't do a combination before the timer expires i want to force close all the app. The thing is that doing what I wrote in the code, my app minimizes and when I press the button of the bottom (the one to see all my open apps) I still can see it is open, not in the second activity but in the first one.

I don't want to remove it from recent application list, is not there where it is once i try to close it.

thank you guys

Comment: Depending on the device, the apps in that list may not be open, but rather, recently opened. You might prevent from appearing in the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list

Comment: the problem is that it closes the activity where i am but it doesn't close the main activity...

Comment: As Pztar points out, you can add `noHistory`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550099/how-to-kill-an-android-activity-when-leaving-it-so-that-it-cannot-be-accessed-fr

Comment: I'm trying but is not working

Comment: can you clear up what you're doing? If you have your activity open and you press the button to view all the apps you want your app to be destroyed?

Comment: I somewhat understand better, where do you currently have the code above?

Comment: @Pztar that is the thing... I don't know exactly where to put it, because my first activity (not te one with the count down, the one from where i call it) is ALSO called in the onStart() of a third activity (the main one). So i have 3 activities:

1 Activity) -> calls second in the onStart()
2 Activity) -> call third 
3 Activity) -> the one with the countdown. When it finishes i want to shut down everything.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:noHistory="true"` in your `manifest` file under the activity you want to behave that way.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

Comment: @ÁlvaroKoke based on your new edit, make sure you add the above to both of your activities, that means not under the `<application>` tag but under both say `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity` or whatever it is in your case

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);`

Comment: not working, i can still see my app in the open ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: not working, i can still see my app in the open ones.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.